# How do I get the time taken by a customer to fill the data from E5 to K5?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

From the below-shown data. I want to know the time taken by the customer to fill the data from E5:K5

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question as it stands is way too broad.

Comment: You could conceivably log all accesses to this sheet or range including the row , column, email address of the user and time into an ascii log and then parse the log daily and calculate the times as you wish.  You could use an installable onEdit(e) function.

Comment: ="LAST UPDATED: " &text(iferror(E5+F5+G5+H5+I5+J5+K5+L6+M6+N6+O6+P6+"x",NOW()),"mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM") - tried this in google sheets but i want this data in google script